# Why doesn't my code for CodeHS 8.3.8: Word Ladder pass the autograder?

Tags: python

This is what I am supposed to do:

Your friend wants to try to make a word ladder! This is a list of words where each word has a one-letter difference from the word before it. Here’s an example:

```
cat
cot
cog
log
```

Write a program to help your friend. It should do the following:

Ask your friend for an initial word.
Repeatedly ask them for an index and a letter.
You should replace the letter at the index they provided with the letter they enter.
You should then print the new word.
Stop asking for input when the user enters -1 for the index.
Here’s what should be happening behind the scenes:

You should have a function, `get_index`, that repeatedly asks the user for an index until they enter a valid integer that is within the acceptable range of indices for the initial string. (If they enter a number out of range, you should output `invalid index`.)
You should have another function, `get_letter`, that repeatedly asks the user for a letter until they enter exactly one lowercase letter. (If they enter more than one character, you should output `Must be exactly one character!`. If they enter a capital letter, you should output `Character must be a lowercase letter!`.)
You should store a list version of the current word in a variable. This is what you should update each time the user swaps out a new letter.
Each time you have to print the current word, print the string version of the list you are keeping in your variable.
Here’s what an example run of your program might look like:

```
Enter a word: cat
Enter an index (-1 to quit): 1
Enter a letter: o
cot
Enter an index (-1 to quit): 2
Enter a letter: g
cog
Enter an index (-1 to quit): 5
Invalid index
Enter an index (-1 to quit): -3
Invalid index
Enter an index (-1 to quit): 0
Enter a letter: L
Character must be a lowercase letter!
Enter a letter: l
log
Enter an index (-1 to quit): -1
```

This is my code right now:

```
word = str(input("your word: "))
print(word)
run = True
while run:
    #ensure he enters a number not letter 
    while True:
        try:
            get_index = int(input("enter index: "))
            break
        except:
            print("Character must be a lowercase letter!")
    #check to see if the index is within the provided word lenght
    while -1 < get_index < len(word):
        #doesn't matter if he enters an uppercase letter becasue the lowermethod will turn it to lowercase
        get_letter = str(input("enter letter: ")).lower()
        #check to ensure he provides one letter only
        while len(get_letter) == 1:
            word = word[:get_index] + get_letter + word[get_index + 1 :]
            print(word)
            break
        else:
            print("Must be exactly one character!")
        break
    else:
        #quits if the index is -1
        if get_index == -1:
            run = False
        #if the index not -1 not in the length of the word ,prints invalid
        else:
            print("Invalid index")
```

There is something wrong with this code. It does everything right, but for some reason, CodeHS says it's wrong.

Comment: I don't understand where you're stuck.  You've identified a fatal problem: failing to flag a capital letter.  You know how to test for that condition.  You know how to issue an error message and loop back for more input.  However, your comment to John Gordon's answer indicates that you can't even attempt to code this.  For me, this is a contradiction.

Comment: In particular, you now know that this is *not* an exception case, as your current code seems to believe.  It's a standard check-reject-retry part of the program.

Answer (score 1):

> It does everything right

Umm... did you actually *run* your own program?

The very first time I ran it, I got this error:

```
  File "sample.py", line 17, in <module>
    while len(letter) == 1:
NameError: name 'letter' is not defined
```

The error happens in this code block:

```
get_letter = str(input("enter letter: ")).lower()
#check to ensure he provides one letter only
while len(letter) == 1:
```

You're saving the input as `get_letter`, but then you're checking `len(letter)`, which is an unknown variable.

Comment: I just fixed that, but it still doesn't pass the autograder.

Comment: Okay, now I ran into a very similar error on `get_index` vs. `index`.  Please come back when you've tested your own code.

Comment: I've just fixed that and I ran it. I've discovered that the problem is that if you enter a capital letter, it will add the letter and change it to lowercase. It is supposed to tell you that you are not supposed to enter a capital letter and to enter another letter.

Comment: The code forces the letter input to lowercase by calling `lower()`.  There's even a comment `#doesn't matter if he enters an uppercase letter becasue the lowermethod will turn it to lowercase`  I'm not sure how you could have missed that.

Comment: Exactly. I need to know how to fix that.

Comment: We've fixed two errors already and uncovered at least one more, so I'm baffled why you originally said "It does everything right".  Anyway, good luck.